# Unable to render filtered array values in react UI

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

- I am new to react application
- I am trying to render the filtered array of objects values in the UI
- I tried with setState in the onClick function and along with the concept of conditional rendering
- But I am unable to render the newArray values after clicking submit button the zip code match text field
- can you help guys to provide any possible suggestions for the issue
- My entire code is available in the below link
  -providing the code snippet below:
  https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-geum6v?file=index.js

index.js

```
Players Belonging to same zip code: <input type="text" name="zip_code" defaultValue = {this.state.zip1} onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
        <button onClick = {this.sports_zip_search}>Submit</button><br />
        {this.state.zip_value && <Zip />}

sports_zip_search = () => {
    var newArray = this.state.student.filter((el) => {
    return el.zip == this.state.zip1 });
    console.log(newArray);
    this.setState ({result: newArray})
    //console.log("result", this.state.result);
    this.state.zip_value = true; 
    //return (<h1>newArray</h1>)
  }
```

Zip.js

```
const Zip = (props) => {
  return(
    <h1>{ props.result }</h1>
  )
}
```

Comment: You have used props.result in `Zip` but not passed any props to the component when you render it nor given any defaults

Answer (score 1):

You're making a couple of mistakes here:

1. You are trying to set `zip_value` as it was a variable, you have to do it with `setState`.
2. Not passing `result` prop to you `Zip` component.
3. Not mapping the resulting prop on the `Zip` component.

And as a recommendation when defining a function in react component try to use camelCase instead of `_` (This also applies for states or props name convention). Also, use `let` and `const` from ES6 instead of `var`.

Your code could look like this:

`index.js`:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import Zip from './Zip';
import { students } from './constants';
import './style.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      result: [],
      zip1: "enter",
      zipValue: "false"
    }

    this.sports_zip_serach = this.sportsZipSearch.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    console.log("Zip Number:", event.target.value);

    this.setState({ zip1: event.target.value })
  }

  sportsZipSearch = () => {
    const { zip1 } = this.state;

    const newArray = students.filter((el) => { return el.zip === zip1 });

    console.log(zip1)
    console.log(newArray);

    this.setState({ result: newArray, zipValue: true })
  }

  render() {
    const { name, result, zip1, zipValue } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <Hello name={name} />

        <h1>XYZ SPORTS COLLEGE</h1>

        <h2>PLAYER DEMOGRAPHIC DETAILS</h2>

        Players Belonging to same zip code:
         <input type="text" name="zip_code" defaultValue={zip1} onChange={this.handleChange}>
        </input>

        <button onClick={this.sportsZipSearch.bind(this)}>Submit</button><br />

        {zipValue && <Zip result={result} />}

        Number of male over certain age: <input type="number" name="age_number" value="18"></input>

        <input type="submit" value="submit"></input> <br />

        Students not from the same state: <input type="" name="state" value=""></input>

        <p>
          Start editing to see some magic happen :)
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

`Zip.js`:

```js
import React from 'react';

const Zip = (props) => {
  return(
    props.result.map(
      results => 
      <h1 key={results.player_first_name}>{results.player_first_name}</h1> /* This is not a perfect key, but given the values at hand */
      )
  )
}

export default Zip;
```

`constants.js`:

```js
export const students = [{
            "sports_id": "F1201",
            "player_first_name": "James",
            "Last_name": "Butt",
            "sports_address": "6649 N Blue Gum St",
            "sports_city": "New Orelans",
            "sports_county": "Orelans",
            "sports_state": "LA",
            "zip": "70111",
          },
          {
            "sports_id": "F1202",
            "player_first_name": "Josephine",
            "player_last_name": "darakjy",
            "sports_address": "6649 N Green Gum St",
            "sports_city": "New Orelans",
            "sports_county": "Orelans",
            "sports_state": "LA",
            "zip": "70116",
          },
          {
            "sports_id": "F1203",
            "player_first_name": "Joseph",
            "player_last_name": "david",
            "sports_address": "6649 N Blue Gum St",
            "sports_city": "New Orelans",
            "sports_county": "Orelans",
            "sports_state": "LA",
            "zip": "70116",
          },
          {
            "sports_id": "F1204",
            "player_first_name": "John",
            "player_last_name": "Micheal",
            "sports_address": "6649 N Blue Gum St",
            "sports_city": "New Orelans",
            "sports_county": "Orelans",
            "sports_state": "LA",
            "zip": "70116",
}];
```

PS: You don't have any `state` call "first_name". And also, I don't know what you are trying to do with the last `<input>`. Hope this helps you.

Comment: ...Thanks for your reply...I worked with updated code given above...still I couldn't able to see filtered array values in UI after clicking on submit button for the zip text field...can you look into it and provide your suggestions. Stackblitz code link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-geum6v?file=index.js

Comment: No problem, but could you explain to me about `first_name` that is missing in the code and the last input who have an empty value? Probably you want it to be a controlled component? @tamilcool

Comment: I've found the issue and know you could with no problem iterate throw the array, you could find the solution here => https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6zjvek (A fork of your project). I'll also edit my previous response. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...it worked well.. the variables first_name and last_name are variables where I missed out for other two objects and yes I want it to be a controlled component...can I know whether you have used first_name as key paramters to display first names. Also, with the first name as key itself, can I render last name too

Comment: Now I am trying with another text field along with zip code search as a form and trying to rendering filtered values, its displaying values and gets reloaded to original form (hiding values). can you look into it and provide your suggestions. providing updated stackblitz code link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-geum6v?file=index.js

Comment: No, I used first_name as a Key because you don’t have any value that’s unique to every student (Like an ID number), you could use index, but is not a good idea. Yeah you could render all of the values from the `students` object, you only need to add other tag  witch is goin to render the information.

Comment: Now I am trying with another text field along with zip code search as a form and trying to rendering filtered values, its displaying values and gets reloaded to original form (hiding values). can you look into it and provide your suggestions. providing updated stackblitz code link: stackblitz.com/edit/react-geum6v?file=index.js

Comment: Its little confusing where I went wrong...if possible can you help me and provide an updated code in stackblitz

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion and reply...code works out well

Answer (score 0):

See this `onClick={this.sports_zip_search}`

This callback when called will have different `this` value when called from some other context, you need to bind it with current context like this, so when `sports_zip_search` will be called from anywhere `this` will point to your component

`onClick={this.sports_zip_search.bind(this)}`

Also in the code block

```
this.setState ({result: newArray})
//console.log("result", this.state.result);
this.state.zip_value = true;
```

Set the zip_value through `setState` as well

**this.setState ({result: newArray, zip_value:true})**

You also need to pass `result` to `Zip` Component like this

```
{this.state.zip_value && <Zip result={this.state.result} />}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply...I took your point and worked with code given above...still I couldn't able to see filtered array values in UI after clicking on submit button for the zip text field...can you look into it and provide your suggestions. Stackblitz code link: stackblitz.com/edit/react-geum6v?file=index.js

Comment: See here https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rjyqcw?file=index.js its seems to be working now, your form was actually being submitted I removed it

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion and reply...the code works out well

Answer (score 0):

To update **zip_value** you have to use **setstate** as you used for **result**

`sports_zip_search = () => {`

`var newArray = this.state.student.filter((el) => {`

`return el.sports_zip.includes(this.state.zip1)});`

**`this.setState ({result: newArray, zip_value: "true"});`**

`console.log("result", this.state.result);`

`//return (<h1>newArray</h1>)`

`}`

You have to pass new result array in **Zip** Component as props.

**Index.js file**

`{this.state.zip_value && <Zip result = {this.state.result}/>}`

and need to iterate array to display each value

**Zip.js file**

`import React from 'react';`

`const Zip = (props) => {`

`// console.log())`

`return(`

`props.result.map(resultData => <h1 key={}>{resultData.player_first_name}</h1>)`

```
`// <h1>{  }</h1>`
```

`)`

`}`

`export default Zip;`

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...I took your point and worked with your code given above...still I couldn't able to see filtered array values in UI after clicking on submit button for the zip text field...can you look into it and provide your suggestions. Stackblitz code link: stackblitz.com/edit/react-geum6v?file=index.js